# How to make two elements symmetrical?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, margin

I'm designing a GUI and trying to add two Button. One to right side of Panel. And other one is to left side of Panel. And they should be symmetrical.
When I change margin Form properties, nothing changes.
I mean left margin of left Button and right margin of right Button should be equal.

[image]

Comment: Tyler please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for asking your question better

Comment: You really need to post the code that generates the output, not an abstract description of it. *trying to add two pictureboxes* -- *left margin of left button and right margin of right button*. PictureBoxes or Buttons? Both? Where are the PictureBoxes? Did you check the Buttons' margins, did you anchor these controls? etc.

Comment: i can't upload images because i'm new here. And there are no any code.

Comment: The Image I posted it for you. **There is code**. This layout doesn't generate from thin air. Code is creating it.

Comment: Margin of what? Form or Panel?? Looks like the Buttons sit in the Panel.

Comment: Margins only work when the layout is automated. After you place the controls they won't be moved by a Margin. This is different when you use a control which does the layout for you, like the FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: Yes buttons sit in the panel

Comment: As I wrote, for Panels and most other Containers Margin is meaningless. You alone are the master of Control placement.

Comment: Do you mean only way is set location of elements?

Comment: Yes, if you want to change the location you need to do that. Anchors are there to keep the distances fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you can to use `TableLayoutPanel` control.
that has `two coulmns` with `percent` values for columns.
and add `pictureboxes` to `TableLayoutPanel's cells`, then set `Dock property` of `pictureboxes` to `Fill`.

Comment: TLP is a possibility but by no means a necessity.